# Find the maximum of a set

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I would need help with the following problem. We have the set $S=\{(x,y,z): (x-2)^{2}+ (y-2)^{2}+(z-2)^{2}\le 1 \}$. I need to know how to find $\max (-x-y-z)$ for $(x,y,z)\in S$. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the objective and the function are symmetric in all variables. It is rather clear that $\min(x+y+z)$ is attained where a plane with normal $(1,1,1)$ is tangent to the sphere, i.e. $(2-1/\sqrt3)(1,1,1)$, yielding $\min(x+y+z)=6-\sqrt3$ and hence $\max(-x-y-z)=\sqrt3-6$.

Comment: Could you explain in more details, how you found the tangent to the sphere?

Comment: I mean where you found the number $2-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$? Thans for your answer.

Comment: I do not have the geometric intuition at all. There is no way how to calculate $\min x+y+z$ for the sphere $S=\{(x,y,z):(x−2)^{2}+(y−2)^{2}+(z−2)^{2}≤1\}$ ?

Comment: It is hard to draw it in three dimensional. Do not you know how to find it by computing?

Comment: Lagrange multipliers, perhaps?